# Efficient pooling/caching of expensive objects

Tags: python

How can I efficiently in a proper pythonic pool/cache objects holding an expensive answer from the database?

My module contains following schematic code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(config.DB) # application shared database
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

class Foo:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_bar'):
            row = db.execute(
                'SELECT bar FROM bars WHERE id=?', (self.id, )).fetchone()
            self._bar = row['bar'] if row else None
        return self._bar
```

Application is creating over its lifetime `Foo` objects to access some values `bar` in the database. The `Foo.bar` property represents an expensive operation, therefore the lazy processing. Instances of `Foo` class are not changing much at all, they are just a read-proxies for database stored data.

Now I realized, that `Foo` instances with the same `id` are created and destroyed quite often. Every time the object dies, the knowledge of `Foo.bar` is lost and has to be fetched from the database later again.

I figured two ways how I could deal with it, either pooling objects themselves:

```
class DBObject:

    _pool = {}

    def __new__(cls, *params, **key_params):        
        key = cls.__name__ + str(params) + str(key_params)
        if not key in DBObject._pool:
            self = object.__new__(cls, *params, **key_params)
            DBObject._pool[key] = self
        self = DBObject._pool[key]
        return self

class Foo(DBObject):
    ...
```

or their states:

```
class DBObject:

    _states = {}

    def __new__(cls, *params, **key_params):        
        self = object.__new__(cls, *params, **key_params)        
        key = cls.__name__ + str(params) + str(key_params)
        if not key in DBObject._states:
            DBObject._states[key] = {}            
        self.__dict__ = DBObject._states[key]
        return self

class Foo(DBObject):
    ...
```

Is there some better and more pythonic solution? Did I oversee something?

PS: I am Python beginner with Java/C++ background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple memoize decorator, here is a generic one:

```
import functools

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    sentinel = object()

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = (args, tuple(kwargs.items()))
        result = cache.get(key, sentinel)
        if result is not sentinel:
            return result
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        cache[key] = result
        return result       
    return wrapper
```

You can use it to decorate the `Foo` class:

```
@memoize
class Foo:
...
```

You can also apply the `memoize` decorator to the `bar` method, and clean it up a bit:

```
@property
@memoize
def bar(self):
    row = db.execute('SELECT bar FROM bars where id=?', (self.id, )).fetchone()
    return row['bar'] if row else None
```

Also new in Python3.2 is `functools.lru_cache` which has a number of nice features (clearing caches, keeping track of hit/miss stats, optional size and type checking)

Comment: Thank you for answer. That `memoize` decorator applied on the class is what I need in the most simple way. I might look into that other cache solution, where more logic is put inside.

While `memoize` can be applied on function, I do have it wrapped in a `lazyproperty` wrapper. Implementation of `bar` function was exposed just for clarity of purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[lru lfu cache implemented as decorators](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/)

Comment: While those look quite neat, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice link. I will use it should my small application grow a bit bigger.

Comment: @André Caron: I could use those decorators in the same way as `memoize` decorator from selected answer. After digesting inputs here I even found that I could use directly decorator `functools.lru_cache()` that is new in Python 3.2.